# Change svg flood-color with Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

How do I change flood-color in SVG with JavaScript?

I have tried this, but it doesn't work. (I can change any other color but not the flood-color)

Javascript:

```
farve3.style.flood-color  = 'rgb(66,244,244)';
```

SVG:

```
feFlood id="farve3" flood-color="#FF0000" flood-opacity="1" in="SourceGraphic" result="result1"
```

Comment: try  `farve3.style.floodColor`

Comment: YES - Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Interacting with the style object through js the attribute names usually change from hyphen case to camel case:

in this case `flood-color` should be `floodColor`.